# Java - Multiple Destinations on Google Maps through URL

Tags: java, google-maps

I am writing a program in Java that creates multiple destination points (latitude,longitude).

And I wish to add each destination as a marker on Google Maps.
The problem is, Google Maps doesn't allow more than 25 markers at a time.

At the moment I use I am creating a a URL string to represent the map, this is an example:

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=33.542550,-112.071399&daddr=33.538090,-112.047250+to:33.523892,-112.093669";
```

and then I call

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));
```

to open google maps with 3 markers present.

When my string includes more than 25 destination points, it does not work since Google maps does not allow it.

Are there any ways around this? and possible make 50 markers in one map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own map with the Google Maps Javascript API that supports as many markers as you want.  Beware however of URL length limitations.

Another option would be to create a KML file containing your markers with a unique name and use that to display the markers.